# MacBook does not list my bootable USB stick in the boot menu

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, startup

I made a bootable USB stick with OSX Lion. When starting up my Mac Mini (which has OSX Mountain Lion installed) while holding option, the USB stick is listed and I can boot from it. But I want to use it to install OSX Lion on my MacBook. But the USB stick is not listed in the bootable devices list. I tried removing and inserting the USB stick in both USB ports, but still it is not recognized:

[image]

Some more info about the MacBook:

- Model: Intel Macbook3.1 (13-inch late 2007)
- Current OS: OSX Leopard 10.5.8
- Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo T7500, 2.2GHz, 64 bit architecture
- RAM: 1GB

I read that this MacBook model should be compatible with OSX Lion (Mactracker tells me that the max OS for this MacBook is 10.7.4). And it should be able to boot from USB (Intel Macs can do this). The USB stick is bootable (it boots on the MacMini, and I used it to install OSX Lion on another MacBook, a MacBook4.1 early 2008). Why doesn't this MacBook recognize the USB stick when booting?

Comment: Could it be that the installation of OS X on the USB flash drive isn't compatible with your MacBook? I don't know to which extent the startup routine checks it, but according to http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1948 *"Intel-based Macs support starting from an external USB storage device's volume that contains an installation of Mac OS X 10.4.5 or later, or Mac OS X 10.5 or later, which is compatible with (or shipped with) the Mac that the USB device is connected to."*. If you make that very flash drive bootable on your MacBook, does it display in the Startup Manager?